# Google maps current position in distance calculator

Tags: javascript, maps

I have a small web app that allows you to calculate the distance between 2 points using Google Maps.

I want to get the users current position and mark it on the map, instead of pre-defining the map center (which I'm doing in the current code).

Being a JS noob, is there anyone that can edit the code at help me get this functionality?

THANKS!

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var directionDisplay;
    var map;


function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var copenhagen = new google.maps.LatLng(55.6771, 12.5704);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom:12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: copenhagen
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    }


    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();



    function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");

    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            distanceInput.value = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
        }
    });
    }

    var showPosition = function (position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    // Do whatever you want with userLatLng.
}
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); 
    </script>

    <title>Distance Calculator</title>

    <style type="text/css">

            body {
                font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
            }
            #map_canvas {
                height: 50%;
            }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <body onload="initialize()">
    <p>Enter your current location and desired destination to get the distance</p>
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="start">Start: </label>
                <input type="text" name="start" id="start" />

                <label for="end">End: </label>
                <input type="text" name="end" id="end" />

                <input type="submit" value="Calculate Route" onclick="calcRoute()" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="distance">Distance (km): </label>
                <input type="text" name="distance" id="distance" readonly="true" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: coords,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions
            );
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: coords,
                map: map,

                            });
         }else {

         alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");

         }
```

That gives you a marker at the user's current location.